# How to Update Stocks When Editing qty in Transaction Details with Dapper on VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, datagridview, dapper

how can I update the correct stocks when editing quantity (Qty) in transactions by adding, subtracting and also deleting the qty. Please guide. Below I tried but the results don't match maybe there is something wrong with my code .

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim itrservice As New StocksoutdetailService()
    Private Invno As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksMaster()
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
    End Sub
  Private Sub BtnRefreshall_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRefreshall.Click
        DataGridView1.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksMaster()
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
    End Sub
 Private Sub BtnUpdateAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdateAll.Click
        Try
            If DataGridView2.RowCount = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("no data")
            End If

            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                Dim detail = New Stocksoutdetail With {
                            .Qty = CInt(item.Cells(3).Value),
                            .Invno = CStr(item.Cells(1).Value),
                             .No = CInt(item.Cells(0).Value),
                             .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                }
                Dim getstocks = New Stocks With {
                           .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                           }
                Dim GetStock = itrservice.GetStock(getstocks)
                Dim stocks = New Stocks With {
                            .Qty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty),
                            .Qty_Stockout = GetStock.Qty_Stockout + (detail.Qty),
                            .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                            }
                itrservice.UpdateStocksoutdetail(detail)
                itrservice.Updatestock(stocks)
            Next item
            MessageBox.Show("successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class StocksoutdetailService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster() As IEnumerable(Of Stocksoutdetail)
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Stocksoutdetail"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocksoutdetail)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
  Public Function GetLoadStocksMaster() As IEnumerable(Of Stocks)
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Stocks"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocks)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Sub UpdateStocksoutdetail(ByVal Obj As Stocksoutdetail)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocksoutdetail` Set `Qty`={Obj.Qty} WHERE `Invno`='{Obj.Invno}' and `No`={Obj.No} and `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
    Public Sub Updatestock(ByVal Obj As Stocks)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocks` Set `QTY_STOCK`= {Obj.Qty_Stock},`QTY_STOCKOUT`= {Obj.Qty_Stockout} WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Stocksoutdetail
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property Invno() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class
Public Class Stocks
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Qty_Stock() As Integer
    Public Property Qty_Stockout() As Integer

End Class
```

- First Data

Table : Stocks

| CodeProduct | Qty_Stock | Qty_Stockout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 4 |
| B | 10 | 4 |

Table : Stocksoutdetail

| No | Invno | CodeProduct | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITR/00001 | A | 2 |
| 1 | ITR/00002 | B | 2 |
| 2 | ITR/00001 | B | 2 |
| 2 | ITR/00002 | A | 2 |

- Data after update

I did an update from datagridview in the table Stocksoutdetail

| No | Invno | CodeProduct | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITR/00001 | A | 3 |
| 1 | ITR/00002 | B | 2 |
| 2 | ITR/00001 | B | 2 |
| 2 | ITR/00002 | A | 3 |

and after update tables Stocks

| CodeProduct | Qty_Stock | Qty_Stockout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 9 |
| B | 5 | 9 |

- Desired Result

The results in the Stocks table should be as below

| CodeProduct | Qty_Stock | Qty_Stockout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 8 | 6 |
| B | 10 | 4 |

result in form after update

[image: result in form after update]

Comment: Oof. Never concatenate user data. You **must** use parameters; Dapper is meant to make parameters easy. Blind updates in this case also looks incredibly dangerous - concurrency nightmare; see "optimistic concurrency" (i.e. rowversion), transactions, and deltas. I don't want to sound mean, but "fixing" this seems actively dangerous, since the design itself is fundamentally flawed - it seems like a "I have the shotgun pointed at my feet, but I can't reach the trigger; how can I adjust my grip to reach it?" situation

Comment: @MarcGravell , thanks your reply , If you don't mind please guide so you don't misstep in the code method

Answer (score 0):

To edit the transaction so that update the final stock becomes correct, the final stock (Qty_Stock) is with the calculation logic (finalstock-(qtytransactionnow-qtytransactionbefore) and also for the finalstockout (Qty_StockOut) with the calculation logic (finalstockout +(qtytransactionnow-qtytransactionbefore)

if there is a simpler way than this again please guide me.

```
 Private Sub BtnUpdateAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdateAll.Click
        Try
  If DataGridView2.RowCount = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("no data")
            End If
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                Dim detail = New Stocksoutdetail With {
                            .Qty = CInt(item.Cells(3).Value),
                            .Invno = CStr(item.Cells(1).Value),
                             .No = CInt(item.Cells(0).Value),
                             .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                }
                Dim GetStocks = New Stocks With {
                           .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                           }
                Dim GetStock = itrservice.GetStock(GetStocks)
                Dim Getprevdetailqtys = New Stocksoutdetail With {
                            .Invno = CStr(item.Cells(1).Value),
                             .No = CInt(item.Cells(0).Value),
                           .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                           }
                Dim Getprevdetailqty = itrservice.Getprevdetailqty(Getprevdetailqtys)
                Dim stocks = New Stocks With {
                        .Qty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty),
                        .Qty_Stockout = GetStock.Qty_Stockout + (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty),
                        .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value)
                        }
                    itrservice.Updatestock(stocks)
                itrservice.UpdateStocksoutdetail(detail)
            Next item
            MessageBox.Show("successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try

    End Sub
```